# TextView inside a LinearLayout, crash with a long string

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Using Android, here is part of a layout xml file:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:textColor="#191919">

      <TextView android:id="@+id/someTextField"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1" 
          android:textStyle="bold" />

      <TextView android:id="@+id/anotherTextField"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I am adding this view (at runtime) to a `ViewAnimator` like this:

```
ViewAnimator viewAnimator = (ViewAnimator)findViewById(R.id.viewAnimator);
View newView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.new_view, null);
viewAnimator.addView(newView);
viewAnimator.showNext();

String newValue = "new value for the text field";
findViewById(R.id.deal_view).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
TextView someTextField = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.someTextField);
someTextField.setText(newValue);
```

This seems to be working fine, but when `newValue` is long enough to take more than 1 line of text in the layout, I am getting a crash:

```
09-06 21:36:48.208: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6561): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
09-06 21:36:48.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6561): java.lang.StackOverflowError
09-06 21:36:48.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6561):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1486)
09-06 21:36:48.248: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6561):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1228)
(many more lines like this)
```

Is this enough information to see what I might be doing wrong?  It works perfectly fine when `newValue` is short enough for one line.  I've thought about trying a `TableLayout` but it seems like this is exactly what a `LinearLayout` is good for.

Comment: Just curious, why are you using ViewAnimator directly? Don't ViewFlipper or ViewSwitcher do exactly that for you?

Comment: ViewFlipper and ViewSwitcher... I'll give them a try to see if that helps at all...  I'm pretty new to Android still, so thanks for the advice.

Comment: Hope you have solved your problem!

But I feel problem is with
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(6561): java.lang.StackOverflowError
This normally occurs due to depth in UI hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help in the comments.  I ended up taking the advice here (dropping ViewAnimator directly and using ViewFlipper).  Better app, but still the same problem.  I dropped one level of LinearLayout containers and it started working fine.

I'm assuming bhatt4982 is right, UI depth was too great.

bhatt4982, post your comment as an answer to get credit for this.